# reuse the last command output at the given index/line-num

Tags: zsh, command-history, variable

```
ls
```

displays:

```
entry1
entry2
entry3
```

How can I reuse the above output (not all of the entries but the entry at a given line, say n) in the next shell command?

Something like:

```
vi $(!!)@3
```

Must mean:

```
vi entry3
```

Comment: You cannot *reuse* output of previous command. It is stored only in memory and not saved anywhere. All you can do is save the output beforehand by yourself in some file or variable; alternatively run the command one more time and manipulate the output with some text processing tool.

Answer (score 2):

You can't directly reuse the output: it's only stored in video memory, as a bunch of pixels; or perhaps in the terminal emulator's memory, but there's no convenient way to get it back from there either. What you can do is run the command again and capture its output this time. This is what `!!` does.

In zsh, use [parameter expansion flags](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion-Flags) and nested substitutions to extract the chosen line. Alternatively, you can let an external utility do the splitting, which here comes out easier to type.

```
vi "${${(f)$(!!)}[3]}"
vi "$(!! | awk NR==3)"
```

This is one of the few cases where you do need double quotes even in zsh, otherwise the output of the command will be split into whitespace-delimited components. If whitespace-delimited components is fine, then you can use a much shorter command:

```
vi ${$(!!)[3]}
```

Answer (score 0):

A classical way to extract a specific line from an output is by combining `head` and `tail` commands:

```
LINE=3
ls | head -n $LINE | tail -n 1
```

- `ls` command generates the initial output,
- `head -n $LINE` keeps only the first `$LINE` lines from this original output,
- `tail -n 1` keeps only the last line from the `head` command output.

At the end only the line at the given position will remain.

So, to continue with your example, let's say this output contains the name of a file you need to edit using `vi`, you can use this output thanks to such syntaxes:

```
vi $(ls | head -n $LINE | tail -n 1)
vi `ls | head -n $LINE | tail -n 1`
```

The first one is the preferred one due to its readability. The second one is the historical one compatible with older systems.

As a last note, some times it happens that the initial command (a simple `ls` in this example) might take time and consume resources to be executed. If you need to grab several lines from its output, do not hesitate to store its output in a variable or in a file so it needs to be executed only once:

```
# Using a variable:
my_ls=$(ls)
vi $(echo "$my_ls" | head -n 3 | tail -n 1)
vi $(echo "$my_ls" | head -n 26 | tail -n 1)
vi $(echo "$my_ls" | head -n 1900 | tail -n 1)

# Using a file:
ls >./my_ls
vi $(cat ./my_ls | head -n 3 | tail -n 1)
vi $(cat ./my_ls | head -n 26 | tail -n 1)
vi $(cat ./my_ls | head -n 1900 | tail -n 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not much experience with zsh, but one possible way might be like:

```
$ p() { i=$1 && shift && a=("${(@f)$("$@")}") && echo "${a[$i]}" }
$ ls
entry1
entry2
entry3
$ echo $(p 3 !!)
echo $(p 3 ls)
entry3
```

For bash:

```
$ p() { i=$1 && shift && IFS=$'\n' a=($("$@")) && echo "${a[$((i-1))]}"; }
```

I admit that's quite bothersome syntax and no error checks.

Comment: [You can make it a lot shorter in zsh](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/208008). Even in bash, for that matter, with `mapfile`.